# Storing multiple metrics in mlflow from a cross validation

Tags: mlflow

I have a logistic regression model for which I'm performing a repeated k-fold cross-validation and I'm wondering on the right way to track the the produced metrics in the mlfflow tracking api.

```
exp = mlflow.set_experiment("all_models_repeated_cross_validation_roc_auc")
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=exp.experiment_id):
    rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=10, random_state=random_state)
    scoring = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba=False, multi_class="ovr")
    lr_scores = cross_val_score(lr, X_train, y_train, scoring=scoring, cv=rkf)
    # log all the 50 metrics in mlfflow tracking api
```

What is the proper way to do that with mlflow? Is it storing it as an artifact?

Answer (score 1):

log_metric cannot store an entire array of values. One option is indeed storing it as an artifact and associcating it with a model, another is storing it as a metric using the step argument to index the value in the i-th fold